# Stored Procedure(Dynamic Columns in  SQL SERVER 2008)

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Im having 3 tables `Project` `departments` and `projectStatus`

> Department

```
ID          Name
1         Software
2           XML1
.            .
.            .
```

> Project

```
ID       Name        DeptID   StatusID
1        Prj1           1        1
2        prj2           2        2
.         .             .        .
.         .             .        .
```

> projectStatus

```
ID      Name
1       InProgress
2       Pending
.         .
.         .
```

I want Below combination:
[image]

I tried this

```
SELECT 
    Status=[Name],
    Software=(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Projects 
        WHERE StatusID=PS.ID and DeptI =1
    ),
    XML1=( 
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Projects
        WHERE CurrentStatusID=PS.ID and DeptID=2
    ),
    Imaging=(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Projects
        WHERE CurrentStatusID=PS.ID and DeptID =3
    )  
FROM
    [MIS_STORE].[dbo].[M_ProjectStatuses] PS
```

Here I want number of columns should retrieved dynamically depending number of departments.
Thanks in advance...

**Edit:Solution**

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000);


SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + Name + ']',
                         '[' + Name + ']')
FROM    M_Departments 
ORDER BY Name


SET @query = 'SELECT [Status], '+
@cols +'
FROM
(SELECT Projects.Name, 
M_Departments.Name AS dept, 
M_ProjectStatuses.Name AS [Status]
FROM     Projects INNER JOIN
         M_Departments ON Projects.M_DeptID = M_Departments.ID INNER JOIN
         M_ProjectStatuses ON Projects.CurrentStatusID = M_ProjectStatuses.ID) test
 PIVOT
(
count(name)
FOR dept IN
( '+ @cols +')) p '
EXECUTE(@query)
```